# Cannot receive notifications in ionic framework GCM

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, ionic-framework

I am using ngcordova push plugin for android with ionic framework. 
My device is getting registered in `GCM`. I get the registration id as well. I am able to store the `regid` in users table. Everything works fine till now. But when I send the notification from my *php* server I cannot receive the notification in my mobile phone. The response of the *gcm to php code* I get is:

```
  {"multicast_id":5214502018855543648,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1439022666580761%156ac804f9fd7ecd"}]}
```

My JavaScript code is.

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform,ngFB,$state,$cordovaPush,$rootScope) {
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {


// ------------------------------ GCM NG-CORDOVA PUSH-----------------------------------
var androidConfig = {
    "senderID": "XXXXXXXXXX"
  };
 $cordovaPush.register(androidConfig).then(function(result) {
      // Success
      alert(result);
    }, function(err) {
      // Error
      alert(err);
    });

    $rootScope.$on('$cordovaPush:notificationReceived', function(event, notification) {
      switch(notification.event) {
        case 'registered':
          if (notification.regid.length > 0 ) {
            alert('registration ID = ' + notification.regid);
            $rootScope.reg_id = notification.regid;
          }
          break;

        case 'message':
          // this is the actual push notification. its format depends on the data model from the push server
          alert('message = ' + notification.message + ' msgCount = ' + notification.msgcnt);
          break;

        case 'error':
          alert('GCM error = ' + notification.msg);
          break;

        default:
          alert('An unknown GCM event has occurred');
          break;
      }
    });



    // WARNING: dangerous to unregister (results in loss of tokenID)
   // $cordovaPush.unregister(options).then(function(result) {
      // Success!
    //}, function(err) {
      // Error
    //})


  });


})
```

My php code is:

```
<?php
// API access key from Google API's Console
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'YOUR-API-ACCESS-KEY-GOES-HERE' );
$registrationIds = array( $_GET['id'] );
// prep the bundle
$msg = array
(
    'message'   => 'here is a message. message',
    'title'     => 'This is a title. title',
    'subtitle'  => 'This is a subtitle. subtitle',
    'tickerText'    => 'Ticker text here...Ticker text here...Ticker text here',
    'vibrate'   => 1,
    'sound'     => 1,
    'largeIcon' => 'large_icon',
    'smallIcon' => 'small_icon'
);
$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
    'data'          => $msg
);

$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );
echo $result;
```

I don't understand where I am wrong. Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem one time back, I recommend making your first application with the link below and let second regid make sure the device is correct, that keep well and that the keys of the application are correct. Try the same browser send notifications, sometimes vary in time.

[add android app](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add)

Comment: now i get in this alert ` case 'message':
          
          alert('message = ' + notification.message + ' msgCount = ' + notification.msgcnt);
          break;  `  **message = undefined msgCount = undefined**

Comment: now i recieve message in ionic i am able to show it in  alert. but how to show this in notification tray.

Comment: Does not show notifications? It is strange, it should appear. Try sent from the URL of your server, verify that the reg id was saved correctly and send alerts from the app when the case is of record. editare my answer. Where do you keep the value of reg id? In your database or only rootScope?

Comment: finaly i got it working thank you i had misspelled the message field

Comment: Excellent! if you mark it helped my answer, Greetings!

Comment: now i want to show multiple notifications with different title and msg. now when i send 2nd notification first gets overwriten. can you help me in this.

Comment: As you are sending notifications? Since your server is the treatment?

Comment: i need 3 reputation to chat :( . i m new here

Comment: Bad luck :( but rarely happens that you should not have problems send 1 or X notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you wrap your $cordovaPush.register() and $rootScope.$on()  functions inside document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {}
like this

```
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
  console.log("insode ");
    $cordovaPush.register(androidConfig).then(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        // Success
    }, function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        // Error
    })
    $rootScope.$on('$cordovaPush:notificationReceived', function(event, notification) {
        console.log(event);
        console.log(notification);
        switch (notification.event) {
            case 'registered':
                if (notification.regid.length > 0) {
                    //alert('registration ID = ' + notification.regid);
                }
                $http({
                  url: "http://192.168.1.101/saveregid.php",
                  method : "POST",
                  data : {
                    id : notification.regid
                  }
                  }).success(function(){
                  alert("Id is saved");
                  });

                break;
            case 'message':
                // this is the actual push notification. its format depends on the data model from the push server
                $scope.notification = notification;
                //alert('message = ' + notification + ' msgCount = ' + notification.msgcnt);
                break;
            case 'error':
                alert('GCM error = ' + notification.msg);
                break;
            default:
                alert('An unknown GCM event has occurred');
                break;
        }
    });
}, false);
```

To get a correct reg id I have made a simple script at http://192.168.1.101/saveregid.php which gets registration id in its post request and stores it on server file which I can access. Get exact reg id from server file and then try sending a notification.